# Undefined instance method "respond_to" in Rails 5 API Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, ruby-on-rails-5

In rails 5 created with `--api` I have an error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `respond_to' for #<Api::MyController:0x005645c81f0798>
Did you mean?  respond_to?):
```

However, in the documentation for rails 4.2 it says http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html

> respond_with and the corresponding class-level respond_to have been
>   moved to the responders gem. Add gem 'responders', '~> 2.0' to your
>   Gemfile to use it:
>
> Instance-level respond_to is unaffected:

And I'm calling the instance method. What's the matter?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
end

# ...
class Api::MyController < ApplicationController

  def method1
    # ...
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml { render(xml: "fdsfds") }
      format.json { render(json: "fdsfdsfd" ) }
    end
```

Comment: "What's the matter?" – Um, the release notes are for 4.2 and you are using 5?

Comment: @JörgWMittag, there has not been any mention of changing meme-responds since 4.2 so it is still very relevant.

Comment: You might want to try the responders gem though. Its pretty damn awesome.

Comment: @max, is there any gem that's not awesome? It takes your breath away and makes you yell "waayyyyy, it's pretty awesome, yyyaaahhhhh!!!" or what?

Comment: There are plenty of gems that are just *meh*. Responders really lets you skip a bunch of boilerplate and DRY out your controllers. I especially recommend it for API's.

Comment: @max, instead of writing 2 lines of code I should use a gem?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

`ActionController::API` does not include the `ActionController::MimeResponds` module. If you want to use `respond_to` you need to include `MimeResponds`.

```ruby
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
end


module Api
  class MyController < ApplicationController
    def method1
      # ...
      respond_to do |format|
        format.xml { render(xml: "fdsfds") }
        format.json { render(json: "fdsfdsfd" ) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Source: [ActionController::API docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/API.html)

Answer (score 19):

As of Rails 4.2, this functionality no longer ships with Rails, but can easily be included with the responders gem (like Max noted in comments above).

Add `gem 'responders'` to your Gemfile, then

```
$ bundle install
$ rails g responders:install
```

Sources:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#respond-with-class-level-respond-to
https://github.com/plataformatec/responders

Comment: Quote from linked source "Instance-level respond_to is unaffected". If like OP your only using the instance-level respond_to you dont need the responders gem, just make sure ActionController::MimeResponds has been included in your controller.