# undefined method respond_to in Rails 5 controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm upgrading an app from rails 3.something to rails 5.  For some reason, I'm am getting undefindied method respond_to anytime I use that method in any of my controllers.  This was working before and I was hoping someone here could help.

```
class StatusController < ApplicationController

  #this throws an error 'undefined method respond_to
  respond_to :json, :html     
 end
```

Comment: You have to add `gem 'responders'` to your Gemfile.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983628/undefined-instance-method-respond-to-in-rails-5-api-controller

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As per [Rails 5 release notes,](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0/actionpack/CHANGELOG.md)

> Remove respond_to/respond_with placeholder methods, this functionality
>   has been extracted to the responders gem.

Add `responders` gem to your Gemfile.