# How to fetch a data using ajax in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to show `country currency code` in text box using `Ajax` with rails.

I have show all country in drop down like this :
[image]

If am select country India fetch country currency symbol in price text box.

I refer some website they said use `Ajax`, but i don't know how to use ajax in `rails`

This is tried code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#manageproject_location").change(function() {
        var country = $('select#manageproject_location :selected').val();
        $.ajax({
          url: 'my-controller-name/function-name',
          data: { country : country },
          dataType: json,
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(result)
          {
            $('manageproject_symbol').val(); // here append courrency sybmbol
          }
        });
  });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
class ManageprojectsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @manageproject=Manageproject.new
        @all=Location.all
    end
end
```

this is database 
[image]

> Note: I don't know know how to use ajax in rails.

Thanks in advance....!

Comment: Have you defined the respected route and `controller#action` for it?

Comment: @Pavan No i don't mention that..?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a `route` which will serve as a `URL` to send data to its respected `controller#action`. In `routes.rb` add

```
#routes.rb
post '/fetch_currency_symbol', to: "locations#fetch_currency_symbol", as: "fetch_currency_symbol"
```

Now in the `ajax`, mention the `url` like so

```
url: '/fetch_currency_symbol',
```

Later, define the action in `locations_controller` which would respond to the `json` format, fetches the currency symbol and sends back the response.

```
#locations_controller.rb
respond_to :json, :html
def fetch_currency_symbol
  @location = Location.find(params[:country])
  @currency_symbol = @location.currency
  respond_with @currency_symbol
end
```

And finally in the `success` call, append the `result` to the text field like so

```
$('#manageproject_symbol').val(result);
```

Comment: I got error like `undefined method `respond_to' for ManageprojectsController:Class Did you mean? respond_to?` where i want to paste `respond_to :json, :html`

Comment: @giridharan Which Rails version are you using?

Comment: rails 5.2.1 ruby-2.3.3

Comment: @giridharan Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38600628/undefined-method-respond-to-in-rails-5-controller/38602666

Comment: @giridharan Did you defined the route in `routes.rb`?

Comment: Yes i did like this , (post '/fetch_currency_symbol', to: "manageprojects#fetch_currency_symbol", as: "fetch_currency_symbol") i added this code in `routes.rb`. And i added fetch_currency_symbol function in inside `ManageprojectsController`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181747/discussion-between-giri-dharan-and-pavan).