# Rspec request spec's empty response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to write a request spec for my first Rails app, but the response object is `nil`.  Rspec is still dark magic to me, so I may be missing something really basic, but given the example [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec#requesting-a-json-response) I figured this would work.  When I run the Rails server, I can authenticate over cURL, and my controller spec works fine.

Here's my request spec:

```rb
# spec/requests/tokens_request_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::TokensController, type: :request do
  context "getting the token" do
    let(:user) { create(:user) }

    it 'status code is 2xx' do
      post "/api/v1/login", { auth: { email: user.email, password: user.password } }, { accept: "application/json" }
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
end
```

Here's my controller:

```rb
# app/controllers/api/v1/tokens_controller.rb
class Api::V1::TokensController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: user_params["email"])
    return render json: { jwt: Auth.issue(user: user.id) } if user.authenticate(user_params["password"])
    render json: { message: "Invalid credentials" }, status: 401
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:auth).permit(:email, :password)
  end
end
```

Here's my test output:

```
Failures:

  1) Api::V1::TokensController getting the token status code is 2xx
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
       expected the response to have a success status code (2xx) but it was
     # ./spec/requests/tokens_request_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just above your expect statement, put these 3 lines: `p response, p response.status, p response.body`. What is the output of each? Also, personally, I find these RSpec helpers to obscure test errors. I'd rewrite that test as `expect(response.status).to eq(200)`. Then you'll see what the status really was.

Comment: @steel It gives me a NoMethodError `undefined method `status' for nil:NilClass` at `p response.status`.  I commented those lines out and tried your suggestion, `expect(response.status).to eq(200)` (thanks for the tip, btw), which gave me the same error.

Comment: Try adding this above your `create` method in the controller. `respond_to :json`

Comment: I had tried that earlier, but `respond_to` isn't defined when you create a Rails app with the api flag.  I followed the suggestions at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35985101/6427913), but I still get a NoMethodError for respond_to.

Comment: Can you try to place `post "/api/v1/login", { auth: { email: user.email, password: user.password } }, { accept: "application/json" }` in a `before` block

Comment: I can and did!  Unfortunately, there's no change in the outcome.  Still `undefined method 'status' for nil:NilClass`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've got this working.

```
it 'status code is 200' do
   post "/api/v1/login", { auth: { email: user.email, password: user.password } }, { accept: "application/json" }
      expect(last_response.status).to eq(200)
end
```

I'm not sure why I need to use `last_response` or how I should have known that (especially since the official documentation tells me I should use `response`), but there it is.