# get :index, undefined method `respond_with' for Api::V1::EventsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, api

When sending a get request to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/events` to test that my API works, I get the following error.

```
     Failure/Error: respond_with Event.all

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `respond_with' for #<Api::V1::EventsController:0x007ff018f2edc8>
       Did you mean?  respond_to
```

My EventsController looks like this

```
class Api::V1::EventsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to? :json

  def index
    respond_with Event.all
  end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `render json: Event.all` instead of `respond_with`

Answer (score 0):

remove the "?"
in respond_to? :json

Comment: That gives me `undefined method `respond_to' for Api::V1:
:EventsController:Class (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Are you using rails 5.0. In that case I think you need to add `include ActionController::MimeResponds` [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35985101/7311465)